# C# Media Player (WMP) Automatic Next Song

Tags: c#, wmp, axwindowsmediaplayer

I need to player to automatically go to the next song in the listBox and play it, but it won't play. I have it where it goes to the next song, but when it changes it doesn't start playing. Here is a snippet of the code:

```
if (axWindowsMediaPlayer1.playState == WMPLib.WMPPlayState.wmppsMediaEnded)
{
    if (listBox1.SelectedIndex != listBox1.Items.Count - 1)
    {
        listBox1.SelectedIndex = listBox1.SelectedIndex + 1;
    }
}
```

I use this same method for the "Next" and "Previous" buttons and it works perfectly.

I have also tried this:

```
if (axWindowsMediaPlayer1.playState == WMPLib.WMPPlayState.wmppsMediaEnded)
{
    listBox1.SelectedIndex = listBox1.SelectedIndex + 1;
    axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play();
}
```

It goes to the next song, but as stated before, just doesn't play.

How can I get it to play?

Comment: how can you solve it jermy, i face the same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use PlayStateChange Event Handler :

```
 private void WindowsMediaPlayer1_PlayStateChange(object sender, AxWMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEvent e)
    {
if (e.newState == 1)
        {
            if (listBox1.SelectedIndex != listBox1.Items.Count - 1)
            {
                BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
                    listBox1.SelectedIndex = listBox1.SelectedIndex + 1
                }));
            }
        }
    }
```